# buttons do not align to the right side

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to make a webpage for practice and I am having a problem. It is not displaying the few buttons on the right side of the page in the header. Tried to make it correct but I am not sure what the problem is. Kindly help me.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.section {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.section1 {
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  /* Replace #FF0000 with your desired shade of red */
}

.section1 ul {
  font-size: 15px;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.section1 .ICON-BTN {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.section1 ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.section1 li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.section1 li div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  /* Replace #FF0000 with your desired shade of red */
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  /* Set font color to white */
}

.section2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.section2 ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.section2 li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.section2 li div {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="section1">
      <ul>
        <li><button><div class="ENG">ENG</div><button></li>
        <li><button><div class="USD">USD</div></button></li>
        <li><button><div class="ACCOUNT">MY ACCOUNT</div></button></li>
        <li><button><div class="LOGIN">LOGIN</div></button></li>
        <li><button><div class="ICON-BTN">ICON</div></button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="section2">
      <ul>
        <li><div>LOGO</div></li>
        <li class="men-category"><div>HOME</li>
        <li><div>SHOP</li>
        <li><div class="women-category">WOMEN</div></li>
        <li><div class="men-category">MEN</div></li>
        <li><div>PAGES</div></li>
        <li><div class="CONTACT">CONTACT</div></li>
        <li><div class="search-bar">SEARCHBAR</div></li>
      </ul>
      </div>

      </div>
</header>
```

I tried using `float:right;` but it didn't worked

Comment: What are "the few buttons"? Do you simply need `.section1` aligned right? Please revise to be more clear about your goal.

Comment: Please use a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to ensure that your markup is valid and look at errors marked in VSC. YOu Markup is invalid as you didn't closed but opened a new button in line 5, and missing div closing tags in line 16 and 17

Comment: As a side note, a Div inside a button is not a good use (block element inside in an inline element), and a list is not to be used to list your entire content. `float` is a property to float an element inside flow-text such as an image within a newspaper article. It is not a property to align elements.

Answer (score -1):

If you want section1's buttons on right side, Just apply text-align: right to .section1

```
.section1 {
  padding-left: 50px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  /* Replace #FF0000 with your desired shade of red */
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: have you tried your solution? Use a code snippet to self-validate your answer. ul and li are block-level elements. They cannot be aligned with text-align.

Comment: @tacoshy, if you read the code, you could see that the `.section1 ul` element has the property `display: inline-flex`, meaning that it will be affected by `text-align: right` set on the parent.  I'm not saying it's the best solution, but don't dismiss it when it works.

Comment: @tacoshy.  I was trying in snippet  after that I have posted this answer you can check if you want it will work perfectly

Comment: Just use flexbox instead of using properties out of the scope and finding unclean workarounds to make use of wrong propertues